# Is there a way to atomically run a function as a transaction within google app engine when the function modifies more than five entity groups?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm developing on google app engine.  The focus of this question is a python function that modifies hundreds of entity groups.  The function takes one string argument.  I want to execute this function as a transaction because there are instances right now when the same function with the same string argument are simultaneously run, resulting in unexpected results.  I want the function to execute in parallel if the string arguments are different, but not if the string arguments are the same, they should be run serially.

Is there a way to run a transaction on a function that modifies so many entity groups?  So far, the only solution I can think of is flipping a database flag for each unique string parameter, and checking for the flag (deferring execution if the flag is set as True).  Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the taskqueue to(mostly) prevent duplication by naming the tasks based on arguments, because inserting a task of the same name as one already in a queue will fail.
Read this for more details: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview#Task_Names

Answer (score 0):

XG transactions are limited to a few entity groups for performance reasons. Running an XG transaction across hundreds of entity groups would be incredibly slow.

Can you break your function up into many sub-functions, one for each entity group? If so, you should have no trouble running them individually, or on the task queue.